# SKPaymentTransaction downloads array is always nil?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a couple of in-app purchases in my app, their contents are hosted on Apple's server. I implemented the functionality of getting the SKProducts, purchasing/restoring them and downloading their content. And I have tested that a couple of times, but now I can't download the hosted content! My SKPaymentTransaction downloads array is nil, although I have checked the download in the SKProduct and it's not nil. I have tried creating a new in-app purchase and uploading new packages, creating new sandbox test account but nothing is working.

Comment: I have the same issue, used to work great, and all of the sudden downloads array is alway empty... Apple and their cloud/itunes stuff, you'd think after ten-ish years they'd get something working

Comment: Ugh....I can't believe it, are we the only ones facing this issue :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and asked on the Apple developer forum, apparently it stopped working a couple of days ago, and only in the development environment.

Let's hope they fix it soon.

For more info see:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/35890

Edit: the issue is now resolved, if you have a similar problem, it's probably due to something else ;)

Comment: Yes, let's hope so. Thanks

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of time... Hope they fix it soon.

Comment: Any solution found??

Comment: @Munahil there is no "solution" as such, hoping Apple fixes their end soon is all we can do

Comment: @Munahil One think you can do is to add you voice to the comunity of developers affected by this issue. We hope to rise the priority of this issue so that Apple will finaly fix it. In the Apple dev forum about this issue ( http://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/35890) please find post by gonzaloju and e-mail him to get in touch.